# Flutter - Colors on application looks a bit different from Figma design

Tags: flutter, colors, hex, themes, color-shade

I'm not sure what am i missing but when applying the same `HEX code Color` from `Figma` or `adobe XD` it looks a bit different on mobile application. I tried looking this issue up, and i think it could be an issue of shades, do i have to apply `Material` color instead of using `HEX Code color` ?

and Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you or your designer works on a MacBook. Here is the problem:

Apple has his own color space (P3) while Flutter works with the sRGB color space. This incompatibility causes the colors to look different. If you want to read up on it in more detail, you can check out this post: https://ente.io/blog/tech/display-p3/